# Proof by induction that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{3^k}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

This is by far my most ambitious proof attempt to date and I'm not very good at them; so even if the proof is correct I would still appreciate feedback on nomenclature, clarity, elegance, etc...

**Induction Hypothesis**:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{3^k} = \frac{3^n-1}{2\cdot 3^n}$

**Show for $n+1$**:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{3^k} = \frac{1}{3} +...+\frac{1}{3^n} + \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} = \frac{3^n-1}{2 \cdot 3^n} + \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$

$= \frac{3^{n+1}-3}{2 \cdot 3^{n+1}} + \frac{2}{2 \cdot 3^{n+1}}$

$= \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2 \cdot 3^{n+1}}$

**Base Case**, $n=1$:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^1 \frac{1}{3^k} = \frac{3-1}{2 \cdot 3} = \frac{1}{3}$

**Conclusion**:

What this shows is that every partial sum of the series $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + ... + \frac{1}{3^n}$ has the form $\frac{3^n-1}{2 \cdot 3^n}$, so that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n-1}{2 \cdot 3^n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

**EDIT**: At the advice of Thomas Andrews, I'm adding the proof of the limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n-1}{2 \cdot 3^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n}{2 \cdot 3^n} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3^n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: You ought to give a *reason* for that last conclusion about $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n-1}{2\cdot 3^n}=\frac12.$$ The rest looks okay. It might have been easier to write your induction hypothesis as $\sum = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^n}$ - then the algebra might be a bit easier in the induction step.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews $\lim_{n->\infty}(\frac{3^n-1}{2(3^n)})=\frac{1}{2} \lim_{n->\infty} (1-\frac{1}{3^n})=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, do you mean something like "As $n$ grows to infinity, $-1$ becomes negligeable and therefore the expression becomes equivalent to $\frac{3^n}{2 \cdot 3^n}"$?
If you mean something else, could you expand?

Comment: That's just hand-wavy. How would you prove the limit?

Comment: @Aleksandar duh. I kno that, he asked if this was a good proof, and I pointed out an argument was missing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, ah I'm not sure...I had no idea I had to prove the limit in the first place. I don't think I know how to do it. Do you mean there's a way to prove the limit algebraically?

Comment: I think he might want to prove, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1/3^k)=1/2$ which is obviously not true.

Comment: @Aleksandar, do you think the last part of the proof makes sense or is there a step missing? Do I have to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n-1}{2 \cdot 3^n} = \frac{1}{2}$? It seems obvious, but maybe I'm supposed to prove it algebraically?

Comment: Another proof would be to note that $s_n \to s$ by the ratio test and $s_{n+1} = 1 + {1 \over 3} s_n$. Taking limits gives $s = 1+ {1 \over 3} s$ which gives $s={3 \over 2}$.

Comment: Note that since the first term is one and the rest are non negative, the must sum to a number greater than one.