# Proof by induction that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n} = \frac{1}{k-1}$, is my proof correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

I proved ($\underline{see}$ [Proof by induction that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{3^k}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317857/proof-by-induction-that-sum-limits-k-1n-frac13k-converges-to-frac)) the case for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^k} = 1/2$, so I thought I would try to prove the general case (for $k$ integer > 1): $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n} = \frac{1}{k-1}$$

**Induction Hypothesis**:

$\sum\limits_{a=1}^n \frac{1}{k^a} = \frac{k^n-1}{(k-1) k^n}$

**Show for $n+1$**:

$\sum\limits_{a=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k^a} = \frac{1}{k} +...+\frac{1}{k^n} + \frac{1}{k^{n+1}} = \frac{k^n-1}{(k-1) k^n} + \frac{1}{k^{n+1}}$

$= \frac{(k^n -1)k + (k-1)}{(k-1)k^{n+1}}$

$= \frac{k^{n+1}-1}{(k-1)k^{n+1}}$

**Base Case**, $n=1$:

$\sum\limits_{a=1}^1 \frac{1}{k^a} = \frac{k-1}{(k-1)k} = \frac{1}{k}$

**Conclusion**:

What this shows is that every partial sum of the series $\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k^2} + ... + \frac{1}{k^n}$ has the form $\frac{k^n-1}{(k-1) k^n}$, so that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k^n-1}{(k-1) k^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k^n}{(k-1) k^n} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(k-1) k^n} = \frac{1}{(k-1)}$$

Comment: That seems correct to me.

Comment: Note that you never really used that $k$ is an integer. You merely need $k\ne0$ for the sum to be defined in the first place; $k\ne1$ for correctness of the partial sums; and only in the end $|k|>1$ for convergence.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, you basically mean that I imposed a greater constraint on the proof than I could have, right? (sorry i don't mean to summarize what you said, I just want to make sure I understood correctly)